# MySQL Is adding subqueries to IN a good practice as to the performance?

Tags: mysql

Does this query

```
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `country` IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `available`
)
```

search for available coutries for each person or it does it once and is as fast as possible?

Maybe it's a good idea to use `INNER JOIN` to ignore those people whose countries are not available?

Or maybe it's a good idea to split this into two queries? (first select all available countries)?

What's the best method?

Comment: @Strawberry SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` INNER JOIN `country` ON `people`.`country` = `country`.`id` AND `country`.`available` - is that the best I could do?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean? What's wrong?

Comment: @Strawberry `available` is a boolean column in `country`, it's not always true. I don't get you.

Comment: Apologies (although you might have mentioned it was bool). A boolean is the exception to the rule! So your query will give you all data in the people table for which there is corresponding (and 'available') data in the country table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a newer version of MySQL and be careful not to add much complexity on the subquery, the MySQL query optimizer will automatically replace the subquery by a join, see this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

> In MySQL, a subquery must satisfy these criteria to be handled as a
>   semi-join:
>
> It must be an IN (or =ANY) subquery that appears at the top level of
>   the WHERE or ON clause, possibly as a term in an AND expression. For
>   example:
>
> SELECT ... FROM ot1, ... WHERE (oe1, ...) IN (SELECT ie1, ... FROM
>   it1, ... WHERE ...); Here, ot_i and it_i represent tables in the outer
>   and inner parts of the query, and oe_i and ie_i represent expressions
>   that refer to columns in the outer and inner tables.
>
> It must be a single SELECT without UNION constructs.
>
> It must not contain a GROUP BY or HAVING clause or aggregate
>   functions.
>
> It must not have ORDER BY with LIMIT.
>
> The number of outer and inner tables together must be less than the
>   maximum number of tables permitted in a join.
>
> The subquery may be correlated or uncorrelated. DISTINCT is permitted,
>   as is LIMIT unless ORDER BY is also used.